# Reports showing incorrect total after adding a new field

Tags: reporting

Issue:
When running the "Case with or without Audit" reports, if there are multiple audits done in the case either by 1 engineer or multiple engineers, the reports gets skewed. Even though the number of audits lists the number correctly, there are multiple entries for the same case number and all have the number of audits with the sum of audits done on the. This ends up in data that is skewed.

Analysis: We have checked the report that the user says that is showing wrong number of records. The report name is ‘Case with Audit’. Here, the report has a field number of audits, which shows the number of audits of a particular case. When the user added Last modified date in Report, then the number of records change from 185 to 258. The user says that it shows wrong data as it should show 185 records only and should not change while adding this field ‘Last modified’ in report. Even we added case audit ID to the report but the issue remains same.

Why does adding the Last Modified field to the report change the total number of records displayed?

Comment: some more details please

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with displaying data from the related records when the object has more than one related record. If you do not include any columns from the children records then the parent record will only display once:
[image: parentOnly]
When adding in a column from the child table, on the same report, if the parent has multiple children it will cause the parent record to display multiple times:
[image: duplicateParentsForEachChild]